# Not compatible with your version of node/npm...?

Tags: node.js, node-modules, npm-install, npm-scripts

```
npm WARN notsup
Unsupported engine for create@0.0.2: wanted: {"node":">= 0.4.0 && < 0.7.0"} (current: {"node":"14.17.0","npm":"6.14.13"})

npm WARN notsup
Not compatible with your version of node/npm: create@0.0.2
```

this is the problem came up ..how to resolve it

Comment: [`create`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/create) was last published almost a decade ago, what are you planning to use it for?

Comment: That is a REALLY old library.  Are you pulling that library in, or is one of your dependencies?

Answer (score 0):

Every package that you install from NPM can specify supported versions of node.

You can see this in the package.json of the package in GitHub https://github.com/TooTallNate/create/blob/master/package.json#L11

This library seems very old. It wasn't updated for 10 years. I would avoid using it.